# MVC Partial View Returns Whole Page Instead of Just the Partial

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial

I have the following partial view named "_transactions":

```
<div id="section-transactions" class="documentsanchor">
</div>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div>
                <h4 class="company-headings">@ViewBag.SecSymbol Transactions</h4>
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I render it using

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("Transactions", "Company");}
```

and this is the Transactions method from the Company controller:

```
    public async Task<PartialViewResult> Transactions()
    {
        ViewBag.SecSymbol = "test";

        return PartialView("_transactions");
    }
```

It's on a page with other partial views.

This works fine. However, I have a button on the page that should get a new partial view and replace the current one. It makes an ajax call as follows

```
    $("#btn_transactions").click(function (e) {           
        var url = "Company/Transactions";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                $('#transTarget').html(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error occured");
            }
        });
    })
```

The issue is that the whole page is returned in "result", that is, all partials as well as the layout, when all I want is the transactions partial. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of  Html.RenderAction , use Url.Action

Comment: If I do that, nothing gets rendered.

Comment: @Scott Did you set the Layout property of _transactions view to null?

Comment: How is transTarget defined in your html?

Comment: <div id="transTarget"></div>

Comment: Yes, I set layout to null as follows and there was no change @{
    Layout = null;
}

Answer (score 7):

Add this code in partial view

```
@{
Layout=null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the route set up in your configs -

```
routes.MapRoute("CompanyTransactions", "company/transactions", new { controller = "Company", action = "Transactions" });
```